# facebook cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, facebook

```
String queryApp = "SELECT display_name, namespace  FROM application WHERE app_id=7256235347";
                Bundle paramsApp = new Bundle();
                paramsApp.putString("method", "fql.query");
                paramsApp.putString("query", queryApp);
                String resultApp = Util.facebook.request(paramsApp);

                Log.e("APP RESULT", resultApp);

                JSONArray JAApp = new JSONArray(resultApp);

                for (int i = 0; i < JAApp.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject JOApp = JAApp.getJSONObject(i);

                    String getDisplayName = JOApp.getString("display_name");
                    Log.e("DISPLAY NAME", getDisplayName);
                }
```

"facebook" in above line showing error..ANy idea?

Comment: have you imported the right "Util" class?

Comment: either you have not imported correct util files or you have not added external lib files needed for this.

Comment: import com.facebook.android.Util;  i imported this..right?

Comment: @ SahilMahajanMj  how to find libraries for util

Comment: i have the facebook util class to in faceboo sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Util.facebook` in `com.facebook.android.Util`

The correct way is to

```
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;

...

Facebook facebook = new Facebook(YOUR_APP_ID);
AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

// all your paramsApp bundle code
...

mAsyncRunner.request(paramsApp, new BaseRequestListener() {
   ...
});
```

Comment: ..iam confused can u be explain little bit more..Thankyou

Comment: If you don't understand this code, then it is probably best to go through the tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/